# Why is my Git branching history flat after a merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-history-graph

I've been using [git-merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) to merge my feature branches back into my `develop` branch but when I go to view my git history, it shows as a flat line instead of the branched history I was expected with git-merge (**not git-rebase**).

When merging the feature branch into the `develop` branch I would:

```sh
git checkout develop
git merge feature-myfeature
```

When viewing git history I see the following:

```sh
git log --graph --all --oneline

* be7c7de (HEAD -> develop) tiam sed tellus faucibus
* 9e365b6 (feature-add) Nulla mattis tortor, a dapibus
* 21838ed Praesent ut feugiat nunc. Ut nec varius lorem
* a1f950e (feature-fetch) Eu dapibus risus dignissim in
* 5917c65 Donec porta venenatis ex
* f67c295 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
* 0c7dc17 Add some sample data to work with
* 87387d7 Structure the application
* 875b0b0 (origin/main, main) First commit
```

I thought merging instead of rebasing would keep the branched history? Why do I only see a flat history?

I'm using git v2.29.2.

Comment: Did anything actually change on `develop` during work on either of those `feature-` branches? Or did you use e.g. `--no-ff` to force creation of a merge commit?

Comment: I've not used `--no-ff` but there weren't any changes on develop in the time the feature was created and completed. Does this flatten things automatically in this case?

Comment: Unless you explicitly tell it not to, it'll get `f`ast-`f`orwarded.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. So with no activity on `develop`, merging without `--no-ff` will flatten it and not include a merge commit. `git merge feature-one --no-ff` will see a merge commit added and show a branched history?

Comment: If you want to submit that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to have a *flat*/no branched look and feel is a [Squashing commits - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/managing-commits/squashing-commits) which take multiple commits from the branch into one commit at the top.

Its possible that you have your setting set to default to `squash`-ing instead of merging. I prefer the squash myself in most cases.

Comment: My .gitconfig is fairly basic and I have nothing about auto squashing in there. I've not performed any squashes on my commits.